# Regex : Pattern match multiple patterns

Tags: regex

I am a little unfamiliar with regex patterns and need a little bit of help.

I have a pattern that I have been able to match to find non ASCII characters through the help of searching this site and using regexr.com to validate.

I have then put this into LINQPad and confirmed that this is working.

```
string s = "søme string";
var pattern = @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+";
var matched = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
s = Regex.Replace(s, pattern, string.Empty);
```

This works, the issue that I now have is I need to look for both a pipe (|) and a tick (`).

If I use this `([^\u0000-\u007F]+) | ([/\|+/])` It is only finding the the pipe and not matching any none ASCII.

I have also tried 
`(^\u0000-\u007F)+ | (|) |(`)`

What I eventually need to do is to get this regex into here

```
RuleFor(field => field).MaximumLength(35).SetValidator(new RegularExpressionValidator(expression here));
```

I would be grateful if anyone can help me with what I need to match the none ASCII, the pipe and the tick.

Thanks

Comment: is it possible to rewrite the characterset not using the ^, so that it only contains the pipe, the backtick and the nonascii [\|\`\u0080-\u00FF] (or something in that spiriit)?

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: and this: ([\`\|]|[[^\u0000-\u007F])+ does not work?

Comment: Your set contains: all ascii-characters that are not in the lower part. You could change that to all characters that are in the higher part instead. In that way you can include the pipe and the backtick in the same set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the regex pattern you want here is:

```
var pattern = @"(?:[^\u0000-\u007F]|[\|`])+";
```

This would match non ASCII characters as well as pipe and backtick.

See the demo:

### Demo

Comment: I have a follow up question if possible, there are two characters and that I need to ignore which are the £ and the €. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Easy: Just add them to the first negative character class, something like `[^\u0000-\u007F£€]`